# Disable jumping between buttons by using arrow keys

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, button

I have a WinForms form with a `TableLayoutPanel` on it.
In this TableLayoutPanel, I have 2 `Button` controls.

I press one of these buttons.
Then I press the Up or Down arrow (<kbd>↑</kbd> <kbd>↓</kbd>) on the keyboard.

The focus jumps from one button to the other.

I don't want this behaviour.
Setting the TableLayoutPanel's "TabStop" to "False" doesn't help.

I would instead like to intercept the event and set the focus to another control manually.
However, I didn't find the event that I need to intercept.

How could I disable this jumping by arrow keys?
Which event would I have to intercept to set the focus to another control?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can handle [`PreviewKeyDown`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.previewkeydown?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) event of all the buttons using a single handler and check if the pressed key is an arrow key, set `e.IsInputKey = true` and prevent focus change:

```
private void button1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
{
    var keys = new[] { Keys.Left, Keys.Right, Keys.Up, Keys.Down };
    if (keys.Contains(e.KeyData))
        e.IsInputKey = true;
}
```

You can read about the behavior and the solution in [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.previewkeydown?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#remarks) section of the `PreviewKeyDown` documentations.

The behavior is in fact implemented in `ProcessDialogKey` method of the container control (you can see [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ContainerControl.cs,35566f49889a8c3d,references)) and you can also prevent it by overriding [`ProcessDialogKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.processdialogkey?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) of the `Form`, like this:

```
protected override bool ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
{
    var keys = new[] { Keys.Left, Keys.Right, Keys.Up, Keys.Down };
    if (keys.Contains(keyData))
        return true;
    else
        return base.ProcessDialogKey(keyData);
}
```